# C++ constructor takes temporary object not working as expected

Tags: c++

For the code below:

```
struct Test
{
    int size;
    Test(int a) { cout << "default" << endl; size = a; }
    Test(Test const & t) { cout << "copy" << endl; size = t.size + 1; }
    Test(Test && t) { cout << "move" << endl; size = t.size + 1; }
    ~Test() { cout << "destruct" << endl; }
};

struct Test2
{
    int size;
    Test2(int a) { cout << "default2" << endl; size = a; }
    Test2(Test const & t) { cout << "copy2" << endl; size = t.size + 1; }
    Test2(Test && t) { cout << "move2" << endl; size = t.size + 1; }
    ~Test2() { cout << "destruct2" << endl; }
};
```

I found the result are different as:

```
    Test t{3};                                       // default
    cout << t.size << endl;                          // 3
    Test move_from_temp = Test(Test(std::move(t)));  // move
    cout << move_from_temp.size << endl;             // 4
```

```
    Test t{3};                                         // default
    cout << t.size << endl;                            // 3
    Test2 move_from_temp = Test2(Test(std::move(t)));  // move, move2, destruct
    cout << move_from_temp.size << endl;               // 5
```

However, I expect these two should have the same results. Anyone know the reason for this?

Comment: Nitpicking about terminology, `Test(int a)` is not a *default* constructor. It's a conversion constructor that allows implicit conversion from `int` to `Test`. A default constructor is a constructor that takes no arguments.

Comment: just by lookig at it from far away, in the first most things can be elided, but in the second you make a `Test2` from a `Test`, that must necessarily involve two objects, because an object cannot change its type.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but if `Test` is using `Test const`, shouldn't `Test2` use `Test2 const`?

Comment: fwiw, removing the includes does not make your code simpler, but it makes answering the question a little harder

Comment: Your output does not seem to be right. `Test move_from_temp = Test(Test(std::move(t)));` cannot call the `int`-converting (default in your words) constructor. Could you check this out?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your output either https://godbolt.org/z/6WeT9veEq (tried other compiler flags too). Please include a [mcve] and the output in the question

Comment: btw your mre can be much simpler. In your current code there are so many things going on while I think your question is just about this https://godbolt.org/z/n4d9qx8E3

Comment: `Test` has one conversion constructor, a copy constructor, and a move constructor. `Test2` has three conversion constructors. There is little reason to assume the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I run your code the result is slightly different (maybe a typo in your Q?)

```
    Test t{3};                                       // default
    cout << t.size << endl;                          // 3
    Test move_from_temp = Test(Test(std::move(t)));  // move
    cout << move_from_temp.size << endl;             // 4

    Test t{3};                                         // default
    cout << t.size << endl;                            // 3
    Test2 move_from_temp = Test2(Test(std::move(t)));  // move, move2, destruct
    cout << move_from_temp.size << endl;               // 5
```

`std::move` is static_cast to an rvalue reference type. It does nothing, only a cast to `Test &&` in both versions.

Based on that, in both versions you call the move constructur `Test(Test&&)`.

In the first version you are then done because of mandatory "copy elison" https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

In the second version you call `Test2(Test&&)` which cannot be optimized away. The compiler just call the method you provided.

Comment: Yes, ```Test move_from_temp = Test(Test(Test(Test(Test(std::move(t)))))); ``` does not increase the calls. They all shortcut to the last Test.